# How to print the values of array after deleting the duplicate values using Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm doing my Algorithms assignment but it is not working.

I'm supposed to write a java program that takes values from the user and sort these numbers in an array then it removes the duplicate values. After sorting then print the array without the duplicate and print the new size of it.

This is my code

```
package javaapplication239;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication239 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input=new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of elements you want to enter in an array");
        int n= input.nextInt(); 
        int a [] = new int[n]; 
        System.out.println("Enter element in the array");
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
        {
             a[i]=input.nextInt(); 
        }

        System.out.println("The Array: "+Arrays.toString(a));
        //System.out.println("size of the array "+a.length);
        Arrays.sort(a);
        System.out.println("Sorted array: "+Arrays.toString(a));

        int j=1, i=1;
        for (int x=1; x<a.length-1; x++ )
        {
            if(a[j]!=a[j+1])
            {    
                a[i]=a[j]; 
                i++; 
                j++; 
            }
            else if (a[j+1]== a.length-1) 
            {
                a[i]=a[j];  
            }
             else 
            {
                j++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("size of the array after deleting the duplicates "+i); 
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }    
}
```

It worked but it doesn't remove the duplicate values, but it prints the write size after deleting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a `Set` for removing duplicates?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input=new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of elements you want to enter in an array");
    int n= input.nextInt(); 
    int a [] = new int[n]; 
    System.out.println("Enter element in the array");
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    {
         a[i]=input.nextInt(); 
    }

    System.out.println("The Array: "+Arrays.toString(a));
    //System.out.println("size of the array "+a.length);

    Set<int> numsSet = new HashSet<int>(Arrays.asList(a));
    int[] newArray = numsSet.toArray();
    Arrays.sort(newArray);
    System.out.println("Sorted array: "+Arrays.toString(newArray));

    System.out.println("size of the array after deleting the duplicates "+ newArray.length); 
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));
}
```

Comment: sadly, the instructor doesn't want us to use any predefined function. He asked us to do this manually and using only one loop for deleting the duplicates

Answer (score 0):

I think first sorting then finding unique elements of array is an easier solution. This the part of sorting:

```
    int l = a.length; 
    for (int i=1; i<l; ++i) 
    { 
        int temp = a[i]; 
        int j = i-1; 

        while (j >= 0 && a[j] > temp) 
        { 
            a[j+1] = a[j]; 
            j = j-1; 
        } 
        a[j+1] = temp; 
    }
```

Now array `a` is sorted with duplicates. I created a new array `a1` to store unique elements:

```
    int[] a1 = new int [l] ; // new array for storing unique elements
    int k = 0; // index for new array
    for(int x=1; x<l; x++) {
        if(a[x] != a[x-1]) {
            a1[k] = a[x-1];
            k++;
        }
    }
    if(a[l-2] != a[l-1]) { 
        a1[k] = a[l-1];
        k++;
    }
```

This is the printing part:

```
    System.out.println("size of the array after deleting the duplicates " + k); 
    for(int y=0; y<k; y++) {
        System.out.println(a1[y]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think @Zigzagoon's answer is quite good (better than this), but if a Set is not allowed you could use this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of elements you want to enter in an array");
    int n = input.nextInt();
    int a[] = new int[n];
    System.out.println("Enter element in the array");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = input.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("The Array: " + Arrays.toString(a));
    //System.out.println("size of the array "+a.length);
    Arrays.sort(a);
    System.out.println("Sorted array: " + Arrays.toString(a));

    //the array a is sorted so you just have to remember the last value
    int last = a[0];
    int differentValues = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {//starting with 1 because otherwise we have no last value 
        if (a[i] == last && i < a.length-1) {
            //duplicate found -> copy the rest of the array to their index-1 (and overwrite the duplicate)
            System.arraycopy(a, i+1, a, i, a.length-i-1);
        }
        else {
            //count the number of entries without duplicates
            differentValues++;
            last = a[i];
        }
    }
    //copy the non-duplicate entries to a new array of the right size
    int[] a2 = new int[differentValues];
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, a2, 0, differentValues);

    System.out.println("Sorted Array without duplicates: " + Arrays.toString(a2));

    //you should always close resources like a scanner
    input.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method sorts the array, moves unique elements to the front of the array, and returns the number of unique elements:

```
static int unique(int[] a)
{
  Arrays.sort(a);
  int j = 1;
  for(int i=1; i<a.length; i++)
  {
    if(a[i] != a[i-1])
      a[j++] = a[i];
  }
  return j;
}
```

Test:

```
int[][] ts = {
    {1},
    {1, 2, 3},
    {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3}
};

for(int[] t : ts)
{
  int[] ut = Arrays.copyOfRange(t, 0, unique(t));
  System.out.printf("%s : %s\n", Arrays.toString(t), Arrays.toString(ut));
}
```

Output:

```
[1]: [1]
[1, 2, 3]: [1, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]: [1, 2, 3]
```